# What index does dataGridView start at?

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if (Int32.Parse(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString()) >= Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text) )
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to check if the integer in the second column is at least the value in textBox4. However, nothing is removed when I run this, so I feel it's not comparing the right column.

Do C# columns count from 0 or from 1?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the if and check the values?
C# columns in the DataGrid are zero-based.

Comment: What are the values of Int32.Parse(item.Cells[1].Value.ToString()) and Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text) ?

Comment: Ooops, I was looping the selected rows, and not all rows.

Answer (score 1):

**What index does dataGridView start at?**

It starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

dataGridView's both rows and Columns  start at 0 index