# C# Get email addresses from datagridview column and send email using Outlook

Tags: c#, winforms, email, datagridview, outlook

I am trying to develop an application (C# WinForms) trying to get the email list from datagridview (column ADDRESS) and send email to the entire list using Outlook application. Below is the datagridview:

```
    ADDRESS        NAME    ID    GROUP
mail1@mail.com     Josh   0011   Main
mail2@mail.com     John   0012   Web
mail3@mail.com     Jeff   0013   Sale
mail4@mail.com     Anna   0014   Lawy
mail5@mail.com     Brun   0015   Sale
```

But I am stucked to get the information from the column and use it to send email to the entire list.

What I tried:

```
            dr = comando.ExecuteReader();
            //SQL query to get data from DB suppressed
            int nColunas = dr.FieldCount;
            string[] linhaDados = new string[nColunas];
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                for (int a = 0; a < nColunas; a++)
                {
                    if (dr.GetFieldType(a).ToString() == "System.Int32")
                    {
                        linhaDados[a] = dr.GetInt32(a).ToString();
                    }
                    if (dr.GetFieldType(a).ToString() == "System.String")
                    {
                        linhaDados[a] = dr.GetString(a).ToString();
                    }
                    if (dr.GetFieldType(a).ToString() == "NULL")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No data!");
                    }
                }
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(linhaDados);
            }
            conn.Close();
```

Then check the column (index 0) to collect email addresses to string "data":

```
                        string[] arrEmail = new string[dataGridViewMail.Rows.Count];
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewMail.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            arrEmail[i] = dataGridViewMail.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        }

                        string data = arrEmail.ToString();
                        

                        try
                        {
                            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                            oMsg.HTMLBody = "<b>Dear all, this is an email for test purposes.</br>";
                            int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
                            oMsg.Subject = "Test mail";
                            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
                            Outlook.Recipient oRecip1 = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(data);

                            oRecip1.Resolve();
                            oMsg.Send();
                            oRecip1 = null;
                            oRecips = null;
                            oRecip1 = null;
                            oMsg = null;
                            oApp = null;
                        }
                        
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }
```

But could not send any email.
Any ideas?

Thnaks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526292/what-index-does-datagridview-start-at, you actually take the name instead of the address

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151641/filling-a-datagridview-from-sqlreader filling a datagridview from reader can be much easier

Answer (score 0):

`Recipients.Add` takes a single email address or name. You need to call it for each recipient.

Or you can set the `MailItem.To` / `CC` / `BCC` properties to a `";"` separated list of names or addresses.